# Running animation on UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation, uiimage

How can run some animation on `UIImage`? I found solution with `UIBezier` path. But it is complex. If I have a solution for how to run animation on `UIImage`, my problem is solved.

You can find example app "Alphabets Tracing" in iPad.

I want the clue logic for the same animation thing that occur in that app on Alphabets.

it is only with `UIBezierPath` or else have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of animation do you want to run?

UIImage
+ (UIImage *)animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray *)images duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

this can do easy animation

Comment: Hi IPaPa, Thanks for the reply. I need something like if I have Alphabet "A" I need some other image to animate on the lines of that Alphabet "A". You can find the example of this in iPad app "Tracing Alphabets".   Thanks in advance

Comment: UIView + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion

this can do easy transforming